# issue with phonegap facebook plugin

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a persisting problem with Facebook Plugin for iPhone.

I have tried many variants with both the newest Facebook SDK and the 
one mentioned in : 
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

I have used phonegap 1.2 and 1.1

Both my application (which is working on Android) and the sample 
version from Facebook plugin fail persistently with same problems:

If I delete JSON  from Facebook plugin, an error :

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJSON" referenced from: 
   objc-class-ref in FBRequest.o 
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

If I leave it in the Facebook directory the code compiles, 
but instead of connecting to the Facebook as with Android version, I receive several javascript alerts e.g: index.html ["..there is_my_app_id..."] ap.facebook.Connect0", true] and so on.

I have found quite a few discussions 
about the plugin on the Net, including advice to downgrade to Phonegap 
1.0.0, but unfortunately I cannot make a downgrade as the plugin is 
just a part of larger application and it needs some features fixed in 
higher phonegap versions.

If anyone has insight on this issue, please let me know.